# How to catch an exception thrown from a callback?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm using `firebase_auth` for phone number verification. Here's the minimal code.

```dart
Future<void> foo() async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    verificationFailed: (_) {
      throw Exception('Foo'); // It throws an exception.
    },
    phoneNumber: '+1650',
    verificationCompleted: (_) {},
    codeSent: (_, __) {},
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {},
  );
}
```

I'm calling above function like this

```dart
void main() {
  foo().catchError(print); // But this code fails to catch it. 
}
```

But `catchError` doesn't seem to catch the error and I run into:

> [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Exception: foo

So, how do I properly catch that exception?

Comment: In general, you don't.  Whatever you pass the callbacks to would be responsible for catching any exceptions when it invokes those callbacks.  Unless the function you're passing the callbacks to documents as part of its contract that it expects the callbacks to throw, you should not be throwing exceptions from your callbacks.

Comment: @jamesdlin It's a bit strange because if I create my own function, say `verifyPhoneNumber` which has a callback `verificationFailed`, the error is then caught. Please check the updated post.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The point is that *you* don't control how the callback is called.  It could be called in some separate `Zone`, called from some `Timer`, or who knows what.

Comment: @jamesdlin So, the bottom line is (1) I should not throw any exception by myself in a callback. (2) If a callback is going to throw an exception by itself, then it must be mentioning that in the contract (or the docs) about it and a client should catch that exception?

Comment: Don't throw *uncaught* exceptions from a callback *unless* the callback recipient expects it.